# How do I change the preview device in Xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

As you can see from the below image

[image]

The storyboard preview is of some tablet device, I need to change this to the latest iphone or iphone 4s, how can I do this? Also I know about the assistant editor and how to preview on multiple devices using the assistant editor, thats not what I want, I want to change the preview in the story board itself

Comment: It's size classes enabled storyboard 600x600 pixel output. It's not tablet.

Comment: Disable size class give u iphone or ipad size, but if u'r design for both then change the `w Any h Any` below storyboard. For preview then open assistant editor , click `manual` or `automatic` then choose `preview` -> your storyboard

Comment: **its called size not preview. Your question is not clear with your actul need be more clear**

Comment: @NitinGohel My question is clear to the best of my knowledge, I do not know the proper jargons, I don't have a teacher, I'm learning by myself, I thought stackoverflow was here to help remove ignorances about topics, If i had known you Xcode called them sizes and not previews (which is very misleading for a first time user) I wouldn't be asking this question now would I?

Comment: i just telling you what does it called to be. nothings else lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Select view controller > click on attribute inspector > select size you want.

[image]

Comment: @Bhargav Happiee coding :)

Answer (score 13):

You need to follow four steps.

1. Press Cmd + Alt + Enter(return). It will show two window.
2. Click on 'Manual' text. It will show menu with Last option as 'Preview'.
3. Select it.

[image]

4.Select device type from bottom '+' button into which you want to see preview.
[image]

Comment: hmm I already know this, I mentioned it in the question that I don't want to see the assistant editor previews

Comment: Is it still valid on XCode 14? I'm having hard time finding it.

Answer (score 12):

In Xcode 9.2, simply go to your Storyboard and go to the bottom, Click View As and choose a device you like. [image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: image for help]

select any viewController and then in `attributes inspector` tab you can change size.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the utilities view and select the simulated size for the view controller

[Utitilities View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrfWW.png)